# Being the only receptionist, is it my job to find coverage for my PTO?

Tags: management, human-resources

I am the only receptionist at my branch.

When I want to take time off, my supervisor has me ask the gals in other departments if they can cover.

It is such a task, especially if nobody wants to cover. It makes it difficult for me to take time off.

Is there something I can or should be doing? Seems very unfair.

Comment: I can see where OP is coming from, because it seems like there often isn't anyone willing to cover ("makes it difficult for me to take time off"). The other thing I thought of is that if they are people from other departments, the boss doesn't have 'jurisdiction' over them, so what happens if they agree to cover OP 4 weeks in advance (or whatever) but then their own boss "cancels" the agreement 2 weeks ahead of the PTO due to their own projects/workload? Things like that are why it should sit with the boss.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The problem is that for an employee to ask a coworker "hey can you cover my shift" is way different from a manager saying "Sandra is out Tuesday, can you cover her shift".   It is forcing the staff to do the manager's job, which is not great for morale.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Seems like a perfectly sensible question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere You're right, I only had 4 decades working at a variety of companies.  But in those 40 years it was understand that the manager was responsible for making sure that there was coverage over vacations, holidays, etc.  Think about it: why does management even exist, if not to co-ordinate and plan and make sure things keep running smoothly?  If the coworkers can keep things running smoothly on their own, sounds like the manager is just an extra cost item.

Comment: What would happen if you got ill and could not work for several days?

Comment: Are you being denied time off you're legally entitled to?

Comment: Also, it's unclear what you mean by, *"Is there something I can or should be doing?"*. Are you asking if there's better ways for you to get coverage or if there's some way to push back against having to find your own replacement?

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable for your Boss to get you to ask around for cover, *however approval of your PTO should not be dependent on you finding someone*!  One of the advantages of negotiating locally is you know your requirements - if you need to go to a medical appointment you know the exact times; if you need to run an errand there is scope to negotiate cover "I can't cover Wednesday afternoon but could do Thursday morning".

Answer (score 7):

It is absolutely within your job duties to go around and compile a list of people willing and able to take over your job duties for a specified time.

It is also within your job duties, to come up with a best case scenario based on the list you compiled.

It is **not** you job duty, to decide whether that best case scenario is acceptable, or trade favors/boss around other employees until this scenario is acceptable to your boss.

Whether your boss has to accept your proposal for paid time off is entirely up to your local labor laws. Common sense says, that at some point they *have* to approve it, lack of coverage is no reason to deny your request forever. Easiest test of this: you *would eventually* get time off, even if you were the *only* employee with *no one* to cover for you. Otherwise your PTO would be withheld from you, which I'm sure is a breach of contract everywhere, after all, it *is* part of your contract, worth money (hence the "P").

So check your local labor laws what they say about it. Know your rights. If you are not supervising others and do not have the power to hire more people, it is certainly not your job to find a replacement to cover for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to preface this answer with it may depend on both your local culture and also your Work Policy.

In NZ, as a generally accepted rule, if you've put in leave with sufficient advance notice (either as per your company policy or in line with expectations) - then it is your Boss' job to sort out a replacement.

However, if you are scheduling leave outside of that time, then your Boss could ask you to organize a replacement.

Consider the scenarios

1: Staff member puts in for a week off holiday 3 months in advance, company policy is leave must be in 2 weeks in advance = It's your boss' responsibility.
2: Staff member puts in for 5 weeks holiday, 2 weeks in advance, same policy = a Boss would be within their reason to ask you to ensure that your shifts are covered as 5 weeks is an unusually long amount of Holiday (despite being logged as per company policy)
3: The morning of your Shift, you get a call from one of your overseas friends that they have had a flight diverted and have an evening in your city, so you ask for that night off = Boss would be well within their rights to say 'sure, but you have to find cover'

Depending on how much notice you give for PTO would determine whether your Boss' request is reasonable. If you are giving more than 4 weeks notice, I would say it's your Boss' responsibility - but again, you may want to check your company policy.

Comment: While this is the way these things should be organized and usually is organized in countries where people have actual work contracts I believe OP is in the US. Which quite probably means they don't have a work contract but just some offer letter which doesn't spell out any of these details.

Comment: I think (might be wrong) that in the UK X days holidays must be requested 2X days before the start of the holiday. So your five week holiday you'd have to request 10 weeks ahead, your 1 day holiday two days ahead.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the country and culture. Generally in the UK finding someone to cover wouldn't be my problem, it's up to the manager to make sure there are enough staff to cover shifts. Managing people is their job after all. Staff taking annual leave and sick days isn't going to be some major surprise - it's expected and should be planned for.

Even if I requested annual leave without the required notice period my manager would either deny it outright, or spend some time trying to find cover then granting / denying it as required. I sure ain't going to be ringing around other staff members trying to arrange cover - that's what managers are paid for.

Answer (score 1):

It may be your job, BUT

If it is your job, then you do it like any other job during your paid work time, not in your private time. You also must be given the authority; you are not asking people to do the receptionist a favour, you are asking them on behalf of the company to stand in when the receptionist has a day off.

If you (the replacement finder) fail to find a replacement then this is the company’s problem, and not the problem of the receptionist. Especially if you were not given any authority. Even though both are the same person.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there should be a system in place.

It isn't necessarily unreasonable for your manager to ask you to do the legwork of finding out what availability others have, but it would be reasonable for him to make an initial announcement that you are asking for cover in an official capacity, not as a personal favour from individuals.

So for example, you could go around with a clipboard of names, asking each person the same question about their availability on or around the time when you want to take time off, and then make a decision and inform the relevant person that they have been chosen to cover. In practice nowadays, you could probably perform the same poll by email.

If this system doesn't work for whatever reason (including a lack of response, or a perception amongst others that there is something improper about you being tasked this way), then it returns to being your manager's responsibility to pick staff (if he oversees all the relevant pool of staff), or to liaise with other managers to arrange to make use of their staff.

Perhaps your manager is avoiding involvement precisely because it would be difficult to make official arrangements, and he would prefer you to use charm and personal favours to achieve the cover.

But I don't think it would be reasonable for him to renounce his own responsibilities in this way. It's up to him to manage the situation so that official arrangements can be made.